# Wordpress cforms session gets lost only in Firefox!

Tags: php, firefox, wordpress, session, browser

I am using wordpress 3.0 with cforms (newest version).

Here I use a multi-page form.

- It works fine in Internet Explorer
- It works fine in Safari
- It works fine in Google Chrome
- **It does not work in Firefox! After Step 2 you get redirected to Step 1 instead of 3. In the debug information you can see it lost the session and created a new one.**

**Does anybody know what I could do to get this to work with Firefox?**

I figured that the other wordpress plugins I use (All in One SEO, qTranslate, Maintenance Mode, Ultimate Google Analytics) can't really be the problem as then the bug would appear in all browsers, right?

Comment: The correct answer is the same as here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661247/problem-with-php-sessions-in-wordpress-with-non-default-permalinks

Answer (score 0):

Recreating the forms as new and putting them on a new subpage in wordpress worked.
Doesn't make sense to me but hey it works!